# Split a chapter into two qmd files in Quarto pdf output

Tags: r, quarto

I'm using the pdf book output in Quarto and I want to break a chapter into two qmd files. The first file `ch1a.qmd` should have a level 1 heading but not `ch1b.qmd`.

My yaml header:

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "Temp"
  author: "Norah Jones"
  date: "11/2/2023"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - ch1a.qmd
    - ch1b.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    keep-tex: true
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \usepackage[subrefformat=simple]{subfig}
```

Contents of `ch1a.qmd`:

```
# Chapter Begins

## Section begins

Some text here.
```

Contents of `ch1b.qmd`:

```
## Remaining Chapter 1

This qmd file has no level 1 heading.
```

Yet rendering this turns `ch1b.qmd` into a separate chapter. How do I tell Quarto to pick up where the previous file ended.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shout out to Mickaël Canouil who gave the correct answer at [github](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/7669). Leaving it here in case anyone else has the same issue.

It seems that at present the only way is to create another file `ch1.qmd` and use short code blocks with include:

```
# Chapter Begins

{{< include ch1a.qmd >}}
{{< include ch1b.qmd >}}
```